# Merge function in mergesort, "vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, mergesort

this is my mergesort function, I can not understand why am i getting always a "vector subscript out of range" error in VC++ express 2010.

```
vector<int> Ordinatore::doMerge(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2) {
int dimV1 = v1.size();
int dimV2 = v2.size();

int dimTotale = dimV1 + dimV2;
vector<int> merged; 

int lh, rh;
lh=0;rh=0;


while(lh < dimV1)  {


    if (rh < dimV2 && v1[lh] <= v2[rh]) {

        merged.push_back(v1[lh]);

        lh++;
        /* the trouble should start here as far as I've seen with cout & debugging */
        while (rh < dimV2  && v2[rh] <= v1[lh]) {

            merged.push_back(v2[rh]);

            rh++;

        }

    }
    else {

        while (rh < dimV2  && v2[rh] <= v1[lh]) {
            merged.push_back(v2[rh]);
            rh++;
        }
        merged.push_back(v1[lh]);

        lh++;

    }
}

return merged;
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Note that in your `else` clause, the `while` loop will never be executed since its condition is guaranteed to be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the top of your loop:

```
while(lh < dimV1)  {
    if (rh < dimV2 && v1[lh] <= v2[rh]) {
        merged.push_back(v1[lh]);
        lh++;                                       // |<-- Problem
        while (rh < dimV2  && v2[rh] <= v1[lh]) {   // |
           ...
        }
    }
    else {
        ...
        lh++;
    }
}
```

When that `lh++` in the `else` is executed, `lh` is incremented and the `while(lh < dimV1)` restarts.  Lets assume that it's made it all the way to `lh == dimV1 - 1`...

- If the `if` condition evaluates to `true`, `lh++` is executed right were you've marked "*the trouble should start here*".
- The next line `while (rh < dimV2  && v2[rh] <= v1[lh])` will cause a crash because `lh` now equals `dimV1` but you're using it to index `v1`.

You can read more about Merge Sorts in this [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).